# How can a fourier transform ever be used for exprapolation?

Tags: fft, time-series, extrapolation

Please excuse a clueless newbie question.

Since a discrete Fourier Transform on a fixed interval is treated as repeating indefinitely, how can it ever be used to extrapolate a time series? What follows the end of the interval will always be identical to the beginning.

Even a simple least square fit would at least give a trend.

How can all that cycle information in a FT be useless for extrapolation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: "How can all that cycle information in a FT be useless for extrapolation?" - How is one to infer from this line that you are asking for a problem that you are facing in a program, as opposed to just looking for a theoretical discussion?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about DSP theory and so belongs on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

How?  By changing your initial assumption.

One does not need to assume that the input to a DFT repeats indefinitely exactly periodic in aperture width.  Assuming that the input is a rectangular window upon a longer stationary sequence which may or may not be periodic within the DFT aperture is also a valid assumption, and commonly used to interpolate/estimate "between bin" spectra.

(e.g. if the DFT result looks exactly like offset samples of Sinc function corresponding to the window width, one could assume that this is the result of a rectangular window upon a single low degree of freedom oscillator, or extreme luck or an alien intelligence that just happens to order all N bins in just such an interesting pattern.  Occam's razor may or may not suggest that the former is a better assumption depending on your model of the input.)

Extending interpolated "between bin" or estimated non-periodic-in-aperture spectra (e.g. after deconvolving the assumed Sinc distortion caused by the rectangular window) beyond the end of the DFT aperture/window may allow extrapolating data not identical with the beginning of the DFT aperture/window.